# Error in storing member function as function pointers in C++

Tags: visual-c++, function-pointers, member-functions

I am trying to store a pointer to a member function in a structure which will be used to call the function later in my program.

Something like this:

```
// abc.h
namespace XYZ {
typedef void func(const uint8_t *buf, int len);
struct holder
{
    // other members
    func * storePtr;
}
} // end of namespace
```

the other file as:

```
// pqr.h
#include abc.h
namespace XYZ {
 class pqr {
   // data members and other functions
   void func1(const uint8_t *buffer, int length);
   void func2(func *section);
   void func3();
   }
} // end of namespace
```

Now my cpp file needs to store instance of this func1 in my structure member storePtr

```
// app.cpp
#include pqr.h
void pqr::funct3()
{
   // Do something
   func2(func1);
}
void pqr::func2(func * section)
{
   holder h;
   h.storePtr = section;
}
```

But I am getting compilation error at line "func2(func1);" as
"error C3867: 'pqr::func1': function call missing argument list; use '&pqr::func1' to create a pointer to member"

I have used &pqr:: to define the scope but it also doesn't solve my problem and I am not able to understand what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers to member function are not the same thing as pointers to normal functions - have a look at the explanation and example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763.aspx

Comment: But, how will I call the member function from the function pointer stored in the structure?
If I store the structure created and use it later on to call the function.

Comment: If it is a non-static member function you always need the object to be able to call it - the object is an implicit parameter to the function. You have either to save the object as well as the pointer in your structure, or change the architecture of the whole thing so that you can use static members - or just plain functions.